# TYPO3 EXT:powermail :- Show Powermail Form after submit

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, powermail

After Powermail form is submitted, I would like to display 'thank you' message at top and show the Powermail form (everything in the same page as before). 
for example: I have Powermail Form in page id=2 and after submit, a 'thank you message' on same page id=2 and with same Powermail form. Till now I could get only thank you message on same page and Powermail form disappears. Is there any settings I am missing?

Could anybody please help me out. 
Thank you !!!

PS: I am using typo3-8.x

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in powermail plugin. Go to tab [Plugin] and tab [Submit page]. In field "Text on submit page" put following text:

```
Thank you. You submit following:           
{powermail_all}
```

Comment: I dont mean to display the info what is just filled but whole form with empty Fields . Your answer will show information what is just filled eg: name: xyz, email: abc@abc.com etc. but I want to display whole form.
I hope u have understood my question, if not, I can explain more.

Comment: My only idea to get this work is with two pages. Page A has powermail plugin with "Redirect to any other Page after submit" set to page B and page b has powermail plugin with same form and "Redirect to any other Page after submit" set to page A. You can set "Where to save Mails (empty = same page)" to the same page ID.

Comment: Thank you but this solution is not for me cause I have a lot of information on this page and doesn't make sense to copy same page. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Maybe there are some other ideas but I don't understand your reason to show form again after submit. Please explain why do you want to do this.

Comment: I am doing a project and my costumer wants this. After submitting form, same page should be loaded with all the other content of the page and also a thank you message 'thank you for your registration....' and below this message a normail powermail form I googled everywhere but couldnt find the solution. .

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a powermail form on one page in two states. You want it filled out and showing a "thank you message" and empty showing fields. This is not possible.